# Unable to authenticate FabricClient to a secured Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-service-fabric

I have a secured service fabric cluster. The same certificate is being used as the server certificate and for client authentication. I am unable to create a `FabricClient` in a console application that will allow me to connect to this cluster. I am using the code snippet documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster) under "Connect to a secure cluster using a client certificate":

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string thumb = "‎1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    string CommonName = "somefabric.cloudapp.azure.com";
    string connection = "somefabric.cloudapp.azure.com:19000";

    try
    {
        X509Credentials xc = GetCredentials(thumb, thumb, CommonName);
        FabricClient fc = new FabricClient(xc, connection);
        Console.WriteLine("Cluster is connected");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}


static X509Credentials GetCredentials(string clientCertThumb, string serverCertThumb, string name)
{
    X509Credentials xc = new X509Credentials();

    // Client certificate
    xc.StoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
    xc.StoreName = "MY";
    xc.FindType = X509FindType.FindByThumbprint;
    xc.FindValue = clientCertThumb;

    // Server certificate
    xc.RemoteCertThumbprints.Add(serverCertThumb);
    xc.RemoteCommonNames.Add(name);

    xc.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
    return xc;
}
```

This code results in

> The X509 thumbprint specified is invalid.

It seems like the certificate does grant me access via other means. I am able to successfully view the Fabric Explorer and
the following PowerShell command also connects to the cluster successfully

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster 
    -ConnectionEndpoint somefabric.cloudapp.azure.com:19000 
    -X509Credential 
    -FindType FindByThumbprint 
    -FindValue 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 
    -StoreLocation CurrentUser 
    -StoreName MY 
    -ServerCertThumbprint 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fell over this exact problem but the cause was quite different.

I was confused in that;

- https Explorer worked (in IExporer)
- Powershell Connect-ServiceFabricCluster worked too.
- Visual Studio Publish failed

I found out that there were 4 invisible characters appended to my thumbprint value, probably an artifact of a cut and paste operation. How, why? Dunno

I found that out only after i edited Deploy-FabricApplication to add this line.

```
$publishProfile.ClusterConnectionParameters|Format-List
```

Just before

```
[void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ClusterConnectionParameters)
```

I then saw the invisible characters displayed as ???? at the end of the thumbprint.

Opening the Cloud.xml file with the Binary editor allowed me to see them and delete them.

Then I could publish my application.

Comment: It works!

I kept getting 'The X509 thumbprint specified is invalid' exceptions.

It was due to weird characters in the end of the certificate thumbprint when copying from the certificate manager.

Comment: you just save the day here. you deserve a beer my friend :D

Comment: Wow, was sure this wasn't my issue, but there it was.  When I copied from Certificate Manager, there was an extra char at the front of the string.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the thumbprint and the common name provided in the sample are just dummy data to so you won't have to post the real values here? However, the problem might be just this, if you run this with the real values do you still get the same exception?

E.g.

```
    string thumb = "‎1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    string CommonName = "somefabric.cloudapp.azure.com";
    string connection = "somefabric.cloudapp.azure.com:19000";

    try
    {
        X509Credentials xc = GetCredentials(thumb, thumb, CommonName);
        FabricClient fc = new FabricClient(xc, connection);
        Console.WriteLine("Cluster is connected");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

This will throw the exception `The X509 thumbprint specified is invalid.`. If you change it to the same as in the Microsoft sample however:

```
    string clientCertThumb = "71DE04467C9ED0544D021098BCD44C71E183414E";
    string serverCertThumb = "A8136758F4AB8962AF2BF3F27921BE1DF67F4326";
    string CommonName = "www.clustername.westus.azure.com";
    string connection = "somefabric.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000";

    try
    {
        X509Credentials xc = GetCredentials(clientCertThumb, serverCertThumb, CommonName);
        FabricClient fc = new FabricClient(xc, connection);
        Console.WriteLine("Cluster is connected");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

You will now instead get the an exception stating `An error occurred during this operation.  Please check the trace logs for more details.`. You get this error because the cluster `somefabric.westus.cloudapp.azure.com` doesn't exist and you cannot connect to that address with the FabricClient, but the certificate thumbprint is recognized as a thumbprint.

Substituting this for the actual thumbprints, Common Name and connection to your cluster will work.

#### Detailed explanation:

Somewhere in the underlying code Service Fabric actually validates your certificate thumbprint. The thumbprint for the certificate in this case is a SHA-1 hash of the certificate (usually of the entire certificate's contents in der format), it is very unlikely that one would end up with   `1234567890123456789012345678901234567890` as the actual hash. [Here is a nice blog entry](https://morgansimonsen.com/2013/04/16/understanding-x-509-digital-certificate-thumbprints/) explaining more about the anatomy of a certificate thumbprint.

Also, you should not use the same certificate for the client security as for the cluster security:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security *(see the Note at the end of the article)*.

> All management operations on a Service Fabric cluster require server certificates. Client certificates cannot be used for management.

#### Checking the certificates

The cluster's certificate should be the one you provided when you created the cluster the first time. You should be able to find it in the Key Vault that holds it. You can also check the thumbnail for it by finding the Cluster resource in the Azure Portal. Click Security under your cluster resource.
The field that says *Primary certificate* shows the thumbnail you could expect from the cluster when connecting to it.

[image: Service Fabric cluster security settings]

When you connect to the Service Fabric Explorer (usually at port 19080) you can also view it if you check certificate provided for the HTTPS connection. If you the click details for the certificate you should see the thumbprint among the properties of the certificate.

[image: Service Fabric]

Before you are allowed access, the browser will ask you for your client certificate, at this point you can provide the certificate that should be located on your computer.
[image: Select user certificate]

After that you should be able to view the certificate details by looking att the security for the page in your browser.

[image]

You can find your local certificate in Windows if you open **Manage User Certificates**, here you should be able to find the certificate that you wan't to use under *Personal/Certificates*. The thumbnail found under details should similarly be the same thumbnail that you present in your code. It should also be present in the list of Client Certificates in the Azure portal when viewing the cluster security. If it is not there, you need to add it. After Azure finished updating the security of your cluster you should be able to connect with that certificate.
[image: Manage User Certificates in Windows]
[image: Manage User Certificate - details]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes that is a dummy certificate value. The real value conforms to the structure of a proper certificate thumbprint and works with the powershell command Connect-ServiceFabricCluster which I would think corresponds closely to what the C# code is doing. Are you able to connect to a secured cluster using this code? Just to eliminate a variable. Perhaps something is strange with my cluster setup.

Comment: Yes, the code above connects to a cluster as long as the certificates and thumbnails are in order. Please see this image that contains some info on where you can find the certificates and thumbnails.
[Overview of interaction, Service Fabric security][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wsxb.jpg

Comment: I added some additional info in the answer on the certificates. My quess is that you might not have one of the expected certificates in the place where it needs to be in order to get this working.

Comment: @ktam33, if the answer was correct and it solved your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, that helps other to find it.

Comment: This was helpful, however I am still a bit confused about the difference between the 'ServerCertThumbprint' and the 'FindValue' field. Should they be the same thing?

Comment: @MarkAtkinson, no they are two different parts of this handshake, the ServerCertThumbprint is the thumbprint your client (e.g. FabricClient) will expect the cluster to present to you when connecting. The FindValue let's your client find the certificate with that thumbprint in the local certificate store indicated by StoreLocation + StoreName, e.g. CurrentUser + My = your local user certs on your machine. It then uses this certificate to present to the cluster and the cluster expects the thumbprint for that certificate to be in it's list of accepted client thumbprints.