# How to validate if service has been deployed in SF

Tags: service, azure-service-fabric

I need to verify if service has been deployed(not test) correctly in SF cluster. Currently I'm using something like this. What else I should be looking at? Please suggest.

```
using (var result = new HttpClient())
 {
            if ( result.GetAsync(url).Result.StatusCode == httpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
    {
        // Not deployed correctly 
    }
    else
    {
    // Deployment success.
    }
 }
```

Update: I was able to use answer below by yoape and [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309236/service-fabric-naming-service-not-forwarding-to-endpoint-assigned-to-guest-execu) and to get app info I needed. Thank you yoape .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`FabricClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient) to query Service Fabric for the status of a specific service.

You can connect to a `FabricClient` from both within and outside of a cluster. If you have a secured cluster then you need to provide a certificate when opening the connection (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41143262/1062217) for how to setup that).

```cs
var fabricClient = new FabricClient("{your-cluster-name}.{your-cluster-region}.cloudapp.azure.com:19000");

var applicationList = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetApplicationListAsync();
var application = applicationList.FirstOrDefault(app => app.Name == "myAppName");
// if null then your application doesn't exist in the cluster

var serviceList = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(application.ApplicationName, serviceName);
var service = serviceList.FirstOrDefault();
// if null then the service doesn't exist at all in your application in this cluster.
```

Now just check the [`ServiceStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.query.servicestatus) of the service you just retrieved

```cs
if( service.ServiceState == ServiceStatus.Active){
    // All good, yoour service is up and running
}
else{
    // It could be either upgrading, deleting, failed and so on...
}
```